# comma before the word "meaning"

Tags: commas

> The sign says "bonjour," meaning, "hello."

Where should the commas be? Are any commas required before or after the word "meaning?"

Answer (score 3):

I would write it :

```
The sign says "bonjour", meaning "hello".
```

Also note the punctuation outside the quotes.